# Flask returning None, possible issue with request.form

Tags: python-3.x, forms, flask

I am trying to build a budgeting webapp, mostly for practice, but I'd also like this to become my primary budgeting tool. I'm not great at Python, but I want to be.

I'm having a tough time of it, which is why I'm turning to you guys.

Here's my code for `budget.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def entry():
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Smith Family Budgeting')

@app.route('/income', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def income():
    return render_template('income.html')

@app.route('/housing', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def results():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        income = request.form["income"]
        return render_template('housing.html', the_income = income)

@app.route('/transportation', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def transport():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        income = request.form["income"]
        mortgage = request.form['housing']
        leftover = int(income) - int(mortgage)
        return render_template('trans.html', leftover=leftover)


app.run(debug = True)
```

html for `housing.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Allocating for housing</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>You have ${{  the_income  }} left to spend!</p>
<form action="/transportation">
    <p>How much is the mortgage this month?</p>
    <input name="housing" type="TEXT">
    <p>Next up: Transportation</p>
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Next">
</form>
<form action="/income">
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Back">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can probably see from looking, the user progresses through the app by entering data for each category. I'd like to keep a running count of remaining budget, but I'm struggling to get past the first part.

When flask calls the /transportation page, I get "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."

I'm not sure why this would be, although I suspect it has to do with the "leftover" variable. I suspect perhaps subtracting the values of two different form data isn't the right way to go about this, but I'm not sure what is. Any advice is welcome!

I can post the templates, although I'm not sure they're needed to solve this one. Thanks so much guys, I'm really glad this resource exists.

Comment: please if you provide the complete error, or at least a way to replicate it.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb, when I expand the error line, I see this: # the body must not be None
Open an interactive python shell in this frame        ​if rv is None
            raise TypeError(
                "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
                " function either returned None or ended without a return"
                " statement."
            )

Comment: in your views body your are dealing with only POST request, but in the view decorators your defining both GET and POST as allowed methods. this may the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `session` to pass data to next route and clear session when user goes back to income page

Use `url_for` for form `action`

In `budget.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "super_secret_key"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def entry():
        return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Smith Family Budgeting')

@app.route('/income', methods=['GET'])
def income():
        session['income'] = ''
        return render_template('income.html')

@app.route('/housing', methods=['POST'])
def results():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                session['income'] = request.form["income"]
                return render_template('housing.html', the_income=session['income'])

@app.route('/transportation', methods=['POST'])
def transport():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                income = session["income"]
                mortgage = request.form['housing']
                leftover = int(income) - int(mortgage)
                return render_template('trans.html', leftover=leftover)

app.run(debug = True)
```

In `housing.html` edit form `action` and `method`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Allocating for housing</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>You have ${{  the_income  }} left to spend!</p>
<form action="{{ url_for('transport') }}" method="POST">
    <p>How much is the mortgage this month?</p>
    <input name="housing" type="TEXT">
    <p>Next up: Transportation</p>
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Next">
</form>
<form action="{{ url_for('income') }}">
    <input type="SUBMIT" value="Back">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```